# AFL (Фаззер) не корректная/очевидная работа. Почему не отображаются очевидные ошибки (краши)?

Tags: c++, debian, segmentation-fault, уязвимости

Начал изучать AFL, для примера написал абсолютно забагованный код, который при обычной работе выдает segmentation fault. (Код **my_prog.c** представлен ниже).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    if (argc == 1){
        printf(argv[0]);
    }
    if (argc == 2){
    char str1[] = "33";
    
    printf(argv[1]);
    if (atoi(argv[1]) == 1){
        printf("1");
        memset(str1, -4, -8);
        return 1;
    }
        
    if (atoi(argv[1]) == 2){
        printf("2");
        memset(str1, -4, -8);
        return 2;
    }
        
    if (atoi(argv[1]) == 3){
        printf("3");
        memset(str1, -4, -8);
        return 3;
    }
        
    if (atoi(argv[1]) == 4){
        printf("4");
        memset(str1, -4, -8);
        return 4;
    }
        
    if (atoi(argv[1]) == 5){
        printf("5");
        memset(str1, -4, -8);
        return 5;
    }
        
    if (atoi(argv[1]) == 6){
        printf("6");
        memset(str1, -4, -8);
        return 6;
    }
        
    if (atoi(argv[1]) == 7){
        printf("7");
        memset(str1, -4, -8);
        return 7;
    }
        
    if (atoi(argv[1]) == 8){
        printf("8");
        memset(str1, -4, -8);
        return 8;
    }
        
    if (atoi(argv[1]) == 9){
        printf("9");
        memset(str1, -4, -8);
        return 9;
    }
        
    if (atoi(argv[1]) == 10){
        printf("10");
        char str[] = "33";
        memset(str, -4, -8);
        printf("NU ohuet");
        return 10;
    }
        
    printf("Pizdec");
    return -666;
}
}
```

Как можно видеть при любом числе от 1 до 10 должна выпасть ошибка.
Изначально я использовал:

```
$ afl-clang-fast my_prog.c
```

Второй вариант выдаёт идентичный результат:

```
$ afl-gcc my_prog.c
```

После запуска a.out у меня вообще не возникала какая-либо ошибка!

[image: Нет segmentation fault]

Следовательно при запуске AFL обычным методом:

```
$ afl-fuzz -i input -o output a.out
```

Не привело к каким-либо результатам:

[image: Первый запуск]

Скриншот для примера (это не тот скрин, когда ждал ~2 часа), я ждал больше 2 часов, но никаких крашей не было.

После чего я решил профазить бинарный файл, что я собрал gcc.
Для этого воспользовался QEMU режимом:

```
$ afl-fuzz -Q -i input -o output ./my_prog/a.out
```

Здесь a.out уже собран gcc.

[image: Выпадение segmentation fault]

При запуске результат аналогичен.

[image: Второй запуск]

Для интересующихся, файл, что лежит в Input, имеет такой вид:

[image: input.txt]

Если передать в виде Сида не валидное значение: `$ afl-fuzz -Q -i input -o output ./my_prog/a.out 9`, то:

[image: Ошибка сида]

AFL выкидывает ошибку, что все сиды выдают краши!

Если передать валидный сид, близкий к критичным значениям (11), то никаких ошибок не будет.

Мой вопрос заключается в том: что происходит? Почему не определяются ошибки? Почему при сборке AFL ошибка пропадает? (Полагаю в afl-gcc обработка таких банальных ошибок стоит, логи сборки еще не смотрел).
Мой спек: Debian машина в виртуальном окружении.

Так же есть второй пример:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
if (argc == 1){
    printf(argv[0]);
}
if (argc == 2){
    char str1[] = "33";
    memset(str1, -4, -8);
...
}
```

Как можно видеть, ошибка должна выпасть при любом переданном параметре, если он один. Но конечно этого не происходит, никаких ошибок/крашей.
Подать сид в этом случае невозможно по очевидным причинам. Ясно, что я неправильно подаю входные данные, но в примерах только так и делают, подскажите, как правильно прописывать входные данные? А также я не нашел спецификации на файл для -i.

Сразу наперед, если изменить input файл на:

[image: Другой input файл]

Результаты буду аналогичными при всех предыдущих вариациях.

*GLHF*

Comment: *"Как можно видеть при любом числе от 1 до 10 должна выпасть ошибка."* - ничего подобного, тут на каждом шагу возникает неопределенное поведение.

Comment: В данном случае это ведь даже лучше? больше вероятность получить ошибку.

Comment: Нет, наличие неопределенного поведения говорит о том, что теряется возможность судить о результатах работы программы по ее коду.

Comment: Так или иначе, если не при компиляцией  afl-gcc , то при использовании qemu ошибка должна была определиться. Как и тот факт, что при подаче не легитимных данных фаззер все таки определяет ошибку. Или при выполнении запись по отрицательному смещению происходит в разрушенный адрес? Или не разрешенный? Или ответ был связан только с C++ стороны, без условия выполнения фаззера?

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что если запустить `.\a.out 10` собранный `afl-clang-fast` или `afl-gcc` он не упадет? А если собрать `gcc`, то упадет?
В папке `input` только `test.txt`?

Comment: В этом примере не происходит запись по отрицательному смещению. Последний параметр у `memset` - беззнаковый, соответственно тут имеет место неявное преобразование в `size_t`

Comment: Да, верно, при компиляции afl-gcc и afl-clang-fast никакого падения не происходит, а вот при обычном gcc вполне падает. Изменил стратегию и использую strcpy, я смог добиться того, что при сборке afl-clang некоторые наборы данных также приводят к ошибке сегментации. Но пока не проводил проверку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В описании `memset` аргумент размера имеет тип `size_t`, можно предположить что передаваемый в тесте размер `-8` станет `0xFFFFFFF8` и программа пытаясь затереть очень большой участок памяти наткнется на область без флага разрешения записи и упадет. Однако переменная `str` после `memset` не используется, поэтому выбрасывается при оптимизации.

`Afl-gcc` добавляет при компиляции флаг `-O3`, т.е. оптимизирует программу.
Полагаю компиляция `gcc` производилась без указания оптимизации, поэтому в ней вызов не был удален и она падала.

`Afl` не поддерживает передачу ввода через командную строку проверяемой программы, только чтение из файла или `stdin`. Придется переделать программу.

На вход программы `afl` подает ввод полученный мутациями `seed`. Т.е. возьмет содержимое test.txt, мутирует его и передаст в проверяемого. Ваша программа рассчитывает увидеть цифры в строковом представлении, а не многострочную конструкцию как в приведенном `test.txt`. Если `atoi` сможет получить из переданной строки цифру из набора проверяемых, то управление дойдет до блоков которые должны вызвать падение. Если не сможет, то не войдет ни в один блок. Мутируя ввод `afl` со временем сможет получить из содержимого `test.txt` строку, которую примет `atoi`, однако это может занять много времени. Чтобы быстрее попасть в нужные блоки, надо чтобы `seed` совсем немного отличался от ввода приводящего к падению.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Как только проверю, обязательно напишу результат. Но остается вопрос, как провести фаззинг тестирование, если нельзя указывать мутирование именно входных параметров? К примеру, как проверить все таки первый вариант? В случае, если программу будет иметь именно такой вид.

Comment: Есть экспериментальная версия afl для фаззинга argv - https://github.com/google/AFL/tree/master/experimental/argv_fuzzing

Answer (score 0):

Для проведения доп. тестов, изменил программу тестирования. Теперь она выглядит так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
if (argc == 1){
    printf(argv[0]);
}
if (argc == 2){
    unsigned char str1[128];
    unsigned char str2[512];
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    size_t length = fread(str2, 1, sizeof(str2), file);
    unsigned char str3[length];
    printf("len: %zu text: %s\n", length, str2);
    strcpy(str3, str2);     
    strcpy(str1, str3);
    printf("PATH: %s\n", argv[1]);
    printf("1: %s\n", str1);
    printf("2: %s\n", str2);
    printf("3: %s\n", str3);  
    return -666;
    }
}
```

Решил сделать упор на `StrCpy`, которая является официально не безопасной. Использовал `afl-clang` для сборки, и при ручной подаче не валидных данных, программа действительно упала.
[image: выпадение ошибки]

Как можно видеть на скриншоте там действительно есть ошибка. При компиляции при помощи `afl-gcc` и `afl-clang-fast` крашей на тех же входных данных не происходит. Благодаря автору @nevilad исправил возможность удаления не используемых переменных при оптимизации, для этого все используемые переменные вывожу на консоль, но полагаю, что в некоторых компиляторах можно происходит оптимизация и другим образом, а так же иная обработка функции.

Главным вопросом остается тогда, как производить фаззинг тестирование в случае, если программа принимает параметры как в первом тестовом варианте.

Тестовые данные, на которых происходит падение.
[image: тестовые данные]